# install db2 database dump exported from linux to windows

Tags: linux, window, db2

i have a db dump from a system which is linux. now i have to establish db on another db2 server which is on windows.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot restore between those platforms because they have a different endian. The only way to recreate a linux database into Windows is via export - import/load, for example:

On Linux

```
* db2look
* db2move export
```

After, on Windows

```
* db2 -tf db2lookFile.sql
* db2move import
```

There are many questions about this problem in StackOverFlow on in other forums. Please check them

For more information, please check: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0005960.html

Comment: I agree to that. I am loggin in on unix box as instance owner. but now when i type the db2move command, it tells 'db2move command not recognized'. Do i need to do anything to run that?  http://technomagus.wordpress.com/database/ibm-db2/transfer-db2-database-from-linux-to-windows/

Comment: You have to load the db2profile: . /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile

Comment: You are missing several steps